# How I can get my own field value from table sys_file_reference?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

In my extbase extension I have model "Item". 
I get images like

```
  /**
     * image
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
     * @cascade remove
     */
    protected $image = NULL;
```

In table "sys_file_reference" and in TCA I'm added filed "preview". It's work in backend.
In fluid I can get image uid from sys_file_reference like `{image.uid}`
How I can get "preview" in fluid from table sys_file_reference? This field isset in table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your own FileReference class that has your preview property and extends the Extbase model:

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference;
class MyFileReference extends FileReference
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $preview;

    // Getter and Setter
}
```

Then use this class in your `$image` property:

```
/**
 * image
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\MyFileReference>
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $image = NULL;
```

Tell extbase in TypoScript to map your class to the sys_filke_reference table:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\MyFileReference {
        mapping {
            tableName = sys_file_reference
        }
    }
}
```

Code is untested but should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository::class);
$fileObjects = $fileRepository->findByRelation(
        'tx_faktesemilivevideo_domain_model_subcategory', 
        'icon_image', 
        $uid
);

if (!empty($fileObjects)) {
    foreach ($fileObjects as $key => $value) {
        $imagePath = $baseUrl . 
                'fileadmin' . 
                $value->getOriginalFile()->getIdentifier();
    }
} else {
    //default image path.
}
```